# Datetimepicker jQuery customize CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a date-time picker from
[here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

For some reason I need to include these CSS and JS files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/bootstrap/js/datetimepicker/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/bootstrap/js/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/bootstrap/tablesorter/docs/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/bootstrap/tablesorter/docs/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/bootstrap/js/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And My code is :

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            // format: 'dd-mm-Y hh:mm',
            locale: 'id',
            icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my real problem is here:

[image]

[image]

Header got too bold and second image no any image for arrow in time.

I want to give it new style for this, anyone can help?

Comment: what is the bootstrap version used

Comment: my bootstrap version is 3.1.0

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6bbc033t/2/ - looks like you might have some other css also

Comment: sory my fault, my Bootstrap is v3.3.4

Comment: that also is fine  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6bbc033t/1/

Comment: my bad.. 
it's not cz it.. 
there is some main layout make this happend.. 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/temp/css/style.css" />
`
Btw,thanks alot for helping me...

Comment: Please do not put "[SOLVED]" into your title, especially when there is no solution included.  Instead, posting the solution below as an answer is how readers know this problem was solved.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is solve my problem,

this is the code if someone want to change the header..

```
table > thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom: 0;
    background: white;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: black;
}
```

and if wants to change button layout of arrow use it:

```
.btn {
    color: black;
}
```

Thanks all for helping,,

especially @arun, thanks alot.